# Boost on windows with codeblocks - error: undefined reference to boost

Tags: c++, boost, compilation, codeblocks

Tons of these errors are popping up whenever I try to use boost in windows with codeblocks. On linux it works fine.

[image: errors]

Even though I did add the boost .lib files and the include path to the GCC compiler in codeblocks.

I first compiled using `bootstrap.bat` + `b2.exe` but apperently that's wrong. A user in another forum said [he fixed it](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/196523/1067455#post1067455) but when I try his method I get:

[image: unexpected]

So to clarify; what I did was:

. Add "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin" to PATH

[image: path]

. Run `bootstrap.bat` which makes `bjam.exe`

. Run cmd.exe, cd to boost folder, enter `bjam --build-dir=C:\boost --build-type=complete gcc stage`

But then I get that error.

Why does compiling/using C++ libraries on windows always net these kind of errors that take hours to solve, while on linux it's nearly **always** flawless -.-

Who knows how to fix this one?

Comment: ¤ One apparent problem is that you have quotes in your PATH variable. Building Boost ain't easy, and they have always had various problems (it beats me how they fail to get rid of the bugs, not to mention the avalanches of warnings). However, in this case I think it's also things like those quotes. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach Unfortunately I already tried without quotes. Just tried again to make sure, and no dice. Since this problem is gcc related I'll try boost in visual studio now, maybe that will work.. I'm kind of fond of CodeBlocks though so if anyone knows; please holla!

Comment: The problem here is that you are building `boost` with MSVC. This produces binaries which are not ABI compatible with GCC. `gcc` is the  wrong syntax to specify the toolchain to use, you should instead use `toolset=gcc`. `gcc` on its own is interpreted as "build the target named `gcc`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique that I use is as follows:

1. Set up the `PATH` environmental variable to include the `bin` directory of your GCC installation.
2. Extract boost somewhere.
3. Open a comand prompt and `cd` into the root of boost (the folder named `boost_x_xx_x` which has `boost`, `doc`, `libs` etc... subdirectories).
4. To compile boost, run:

   > bootstrap.bat
   >
   > b2 toolset=gcc variant=release link=static threading=multi install

This will install boost to `C:\Boost`. If you want to install it elsewhere use the `--build-dir=` option when running `b2`.

Comment: @natly: No problem! In case I forget to keep this answer up-to-date, I maintain a reference for this in the [build instructions](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/hourglassii/index.php?title=Windows_(MinGW)_Project_Setup) for a personal project of mine.